# Сначала переоткрой, а потом подумай, не проголосовать ли за закрытие

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Нормально ли что вопрос, за переоткрытие которого я уже голосовал, попадается мне в очереди проверок на закрытие?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/44694
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/468108/revisions

Comment: это система намекает, что не стоило переоткрывать вопрос )

Comment: @PashaPash, ждём 11 плюсиков твоему комменту?

Comment: один уже есть... если серьезно - то система просто не трекает кто что переоткрывал. максимум - отфильтровывает поставленые тобой же тревоги в очереди LQ. и это уже где-то обсуждалось на мете, решили что все норм.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589/ и http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1429/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно! Вдруг с тех пор вопрос испортился или вы стали злее. А если вы по-прежнему уверены, что вопрос должен быть открытым — нажмите кнопку «оставить открытым». Этим самым вы увеличиваете шансы вопроса и ещё раз подтверждаете свое мнение.

Так что это даже небольшой эксплоит. Система позволяет вам дважды проголосовать за открытие вопроса.