# В очереди проверок показываются вопросы, за который уже проголосовал

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

В очереди проверок показываются вопросы, за который я уже голосовал (не из очереди, а из общего списка). При этом все кнопки доступны, но при нажатии на "Рекомендуется закрыть" выводится, что я уже за этот вопрос голосовал Х минут назад. Зачем же мне тогда еще раз показывать этот вопрос?  В итоге остается только "Пропустить".

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1868/178988 - но вроде тогда работало.